# How to work with Redux reducers and server API

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

What is a better way to create reducers with handleActions in redux-actions:
 1. Create reducers for each CRUD operations (like add data, delete data) and combine it. How set initialState in this case?
 2. Set actions in one reducer (fetchDeleteDataRequest, fetchDeleteDataSuccess, fetchAddDataRequest, fetchAddDataSuccess by example)?

Answer (score 0):

You can have sperate reducers and or common reducers to add or delete data that is up to you. If you are considering separate actions for **add** and **delete** you will need to keep the data consistent. But having a common function to deal with the CRUD operations is ideal since this will reduce the amount of code that you have to use but you will need a way to distinguish them as well (maybe bypassing some variable **ADD** or **DELETE**). let's consider and list of items that you will be adding or deleting. This list can be an empty array in the beginning (**initialState**) and pass it as props to your component.

**Actions**

```
export const addDeleteItem = data => dispatch => {
  // you can perform REST calls here
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_REMOVE_DATA,
    payload: data
  });
};
```

**Reducers**

```
let initialState = {
 items:[]
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_REMOVE_DATA:
      if(action.payload.event === 'ADD'){
        return {...state,items:[...state.items,action.payload.item]}
      }else if(action.payload.event === 'DELETE'){
        return {...state,items:state.items.filter(item=>item.id !== action.payload.item.id)}
      }else if (action.payload.event === 'UPDATE'){
       //handle your update code
      }
  }
}
```

This is just an example you can follow something like this to avoid code duplication.

Comment: And what if I have 3 actions for only create operation(fetchRequest, fetchSuccess, Failure) how can I separate it in different reducers and save data state like one? I will get 12 actions for one reducer if won't do it.
`[fetchDeleteDataSuccess](state, { payload }) {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.filter(item => !payload.includes(item._id)),
        isFetching: false,
        error: null,
      };
    },`